# Jquery-confirm launches window infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a listener of the focus event of an input but when entering that event, the modal is launched indefinitely.

```js
$('.input').on('focus',function() {
    $.confirm({
        theme: 'material',
        title: 'Atention',
        content: '¿Content?',
        useBootstrap: false,
        boxWidth:'200px'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<input type="date"  class="input">
```

But if I do something like the confirmation window is not displayed indefinitely

```
$(this).confirm({...});
```

What is the difference of using `$.confirm` vs `$(this).confirm` and why is the window shown so many times

**To which the $ symbol refers is not to the input? Is not the same as (this) that refers to the input?**

Comment: I think in this case, you will need to bind the confirm event directly to your element, which means using $(this) to bind

Comment: it is not the confirm that is the issue, its the assigned event handler

Answer (score 0):

If you only need your event to happen once, considering using `$('.input').one('focus',function(e) { ... }` instead.

Something in the jQuery Confirm library is causing the focus to shift around elements on the page, triggering your event multiple times. The same thing also happens if you trigger an `alert`, since the focus is taken and then returned to the input box.

Comment: To which the $ symbol refers is not to the input? Is not the same as (this) that refers to the input?

Comment: @DarkFenix This change makes your event fire only once using the [`one` jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/one/), which stops it being infinitely triggered due to focus changing through the elements.